# Crash when I try to insert Date as Key on Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am configuring my database according to my documentation. I did all the initial configuration: I will put the code below

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        if (Auth.auth().currentUser) != nil {
            presentHome()
        } else {
            presentSignIn()
        }

        return true
    }
```

The problem is that when I create the database reference and having insert something I get this error:

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

ViewController:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

@IBAction func saveTask(_ sender: Any) {
        let task:[String:Any] = [
            "title":self.titleTxtField.text!,
            "type":type!,
            "observations":"Teste de tarefa",
            "finished":false,
            "images":[
                "image1":"https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg",
                "image2":"http://www.planwallpaper.com/images#static/images/beautiful-sunset-images-196063.jpg"
                ]
        ]

        let date = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        ref.child("\(self.user!.uid)/tasks/\(date)").setValue(["teste":"teste"])
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is on this line:

```
let date = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

This print some characters which are not allowed to be entered as child key on Firebase

So, if you want a structure like this:

```
root
--- year
------ month
--------- day
```

Try to do this:

1. Extract the DateComponents from the Date
2. Create a new String with the results

And add the new string as child with this code:

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: yourDate)
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child("root/\(components.year!)/\(components.month!)/\(components.day!)")
```

Comment: This is not my problem. If I remove the date and pass a simple string I have the same error

Comment: please, provide some screen of your error code and I will investigate

Comment: You were right. But I also had a configuration error. Hitting the two I was able to record my data!